# Help with logical quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let $L(x,y)$ be "$x$ loves $y$". Then is the statement: "Nobody loves everybody" equivalent to  $$∀x ∀y \overline{L(x,y)} $$

Comment: If you had nobody though, would that be a variable? From my viewpoint, you are defining x and y to be SOMETHING, part of a set, nobody would just be the zero-set, since it consists of nothing. I believe a better way to express it would be for the zeroith set of x, and for all y, L(x,y). If you wanted the opposite of love, it would be hate, so if you said "Everybody hates/doesn't love everybody" it would be how you wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first order sentence you wrote, $\forall x\,\forall y\, \neg\, L(x,y)$, means "nobody loves anybody", as Frentos observes. Notice that "nobody" means "there isn't somebody" — "nobody is such that $P$" means "there is no person $x$ such that $P(x)$", which is to say $\neg\exists x\, P(x)$.

In this case, $P(x)$ is "$x$ loves everybody". We can render that with the formula $\forall y\, L(x,y)$. Thus "nobody loves everybody" can be symbolized by $$\neg\exists x\,\forall y\, L(x,y).$$ Using the rules for interchanging negation and quantifiers, $\neg\forall\equiv\exists\neg$ and $\neg\exists\equiv\forall\neg$, this is equivalent to $$\forall x\,\exists y\, \neg\, L(x,y).$$

Answer (score 1):

Your current answer, $∀x ∀y \overline{L(x,y)}$, says for every pair of people $x$ and $y$, $x$ does not love $y$.  That is, nobody loves anybody.

Hint: Think about "nobody has property $P$" as "there does not exist a person $x$ such that $x$ has property $P$"

Hint: How would you write "somebody loves everybody"? I.e. "there is a person $x$ such that $x$ loves everybody"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want if L(x,y) means x loves y that there is no x such that for all y L(x,y). That is, "not (there exists x[ for all y L(x,y) ])." which can be symbolized from this English version.